# iOS Developer Enterprise Program and iOS Developer Program

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm got an account for iOS Developer Program.

1. Can I upgrade my current account to iOS Developer Enterprise Program?
2. Can iOS Developer Enterprise Program allow developer to distribute the application to app store?
3. Can iOS Developer Enterprise Program and iOS Developer Program account join together? Or it's different account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, once you buy one of a certain type, it stays that type
2. No, only enterprise distribution is allowed for enterprise accounts
3. No - they must remain separate accounts

Comment: This. Also, your company will need a D-U-N-S number in order to register for the program. More information here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not upgrade your current account. You have to create a new one for enterprise.
2. Basically an enterprise account is used for internal purpose to distribute the build within your organisation but you can also upload a build to the **AppStore**. For that you have to pay $299.
3. No, Enterprise and Developer both are separate accounts.

For more details about Enterprise accounts: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

1. No, once you buy one of a certain type, it stays that type
2. No, only enterprise distribution is allowed for enterprise accounts
3. No, they must remain separate accounts